# Copy folder and its content in ruby

Tags: ruby

My project structure looks like this:

```
Project_root
 |__Templates
 |  |__Report_Template
 |
 |__Product
    |__product.rb
```

What code should I write in `product.rb` in order to copy `Report_Template` folder and its content into `Product` folder?
I tried to use `FileUtils.cp_r`, but then I will have to give full path of source folder and if in a future I move `Project_root`, there will be issues.

Comment: I think you're on the right path with `FileUtils.cp_r`, but you will have to find a way to get the path to one of `Project_root`, `Project_root/Product`, or `Project_root/Product/product.rb` at runtime..

Comment: how can I get to Project_root?

Comment: Maybe take a look around [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp_r), perhaps the next entry will give you an idea. I don't know ruby, but you can usually either get the "working directory", the path from which the program is started, and the path to the program or script that is executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kenney says, you can get the path from which the program started, in `__dir__`. Here I use `Pathname` class for easier path manipulation, but it is entirely optional (you can use `File#join` etc. just as well):

```
require 'pathname'
templates_pathname = Pathname.new(__dir__) + "../Templates/Report_Template"
# optional:
templates_path = templates_pathname.realpath.to_s
```

`Pathname#realpath` will give you the absolute path, if you need it; but `FileUtils#cp_r` will happily accept a `Pathname` (i.e. `templates_pathname` above), and won't mind it's not absolute.